# MPI Radix-Sort implementation low speed-up

Tags: c, parallel-processing, mpi, openmp, openmpi

I tried to implement a solution for the Radix-Sort algorithm using MPI to parallelize execution. My idea was to have each process compute the vector of the counts locally and then aggregate the results on the root process that does the sorting. With this solution I noticed a maximum speed up of just 1.5 compared to the sequential version.

I was wondering if a similar speed up was normal or if a different MPI implementation could be adopted to improve this result. I've seen around that you might think about sorting subarrays on processes but I don't quite understand how to put these sorted blocks together to get the final sorted array efficiently.

**Sequential**:

```
/**
 * @brief This function allows to find the maximum in an array.
 * @param arr      array.
 * @param n        array size.
 */
int getMax(int* array, int n) {
  int max = array[0];
  for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
    if (array[i] > max)
      max = array[i];
  return max;
}


/**
 * @brief The main function that sorts the array of size 'size'.
 * @param array          array.
 * @param size           array size.
 * @param digit          number which represent ciphers.
 */
void countingSort(int* array, int size, int digit) {
  int* output= (int*) malloc(sizeof(int)*(size + 1));
  int count[10]={0};

  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    count[(array[i] / digit) % 10]++;
    
  for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
    count[i] += count[i - 1];

  for (int i = size - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    output[count[(array[i] / digit) % 10] - 1] = array[i];
    count[(array[i] / digit) % 10]--;
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    array[i] = output[i];
  free(output);
}


/**
 * @brief The function that takes the max and starts the sorting process.
 * @param array          array.
 * @param size           array size.
 */
void radixsort(int* array, int size) {
  int max = getMax(array, size);
  for (int digit = 1; max / digit > 0; digit *= 10)
    countingSort(array, size, digit);
}
```

**MPI version**:

```
/**
 * @brief This function allows to find the maximum in an array.
 * @param arr      array.
 * @param n        array size.
 */
int getMax(int* arr, int n) { 
    int max = arr[0]; 
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) 
        if (arr[i] > max) 
            max = arr[i]; 
    return max; 
} 


/**
 * @brief The main function that sorts the array of size n.
 * @param array          array.
 * @param rec_buf        sub-array of each process.
 * @param n              array size.
 * @param digit          number which represent ciphers.
 * @param num_process    number of processes.
 * @param rank           rank of the current process.
 * @param dim            dimension of the rec_buf.
 */
void countingSort(int* array, int* rec_buf, int n, int digit, int num_process, int rank, int dim) {
    // Compute local count for each processes
    int i, local_count[10] = {0};
    
    for (i = 0; i < dim; i++) {
        local_count[(rec_buf[i] / digit) % 10]++;
    }

    // Reduce all the sub counts to root process
    if (rank == 0) {
        int count[10] = {0};
        MPI_Reduce(local_count, count, 10, MPI_INT, MPI_SUM, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);


        for (i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
            count[i] += count[i - 1];
        }
       int* temp_array = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int) * n);
        for (i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--) { 
            temp_array[count[(array[i] / digit) % 10] - 1] = array[i]; 
            count[(array[i] / digit) % 10]--; 
        }
        memcpy(array, temp_array, sizeof(int) * n);
        free(temp_array);

    } else {
        MPI_Reduce(local_count, 0, 10, MPI_INT, MPI_SUM, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }
}

/**
 * @brief The function that separates the array in subarray and starts the sorting process.
 * @param array          array.
 * @param n              array size.
 * @param num_process    number of processes.
 * @param rank           rank of the current process.
 */
void radix_sort(int* array, int n, int num_process, int rank) {
    int rem = n%num_process; // elements remaining after division among processes
    int dim, displacement;

    if ( rank < rem) {
        dim = n/num_process+1;
        displacement = rank * dim;
    }
    else { 
        dim = n/num_process;
        displacement = rank * dim + rem;
    }
    int* rec_buf= (int*) malloc(sizeof(int)*dim) ;       
    int* sendcounts = NULL;
    int* displs = NULL;
    if (rank == 0) {
        sendcounts = malloc(sizeof(int)*num_process);
        displs = malloc(sizeof(int)*num_process);
    }

    MPI_Gather(&dim,1,MPI_INT, sendcounts, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Gather(&displacement, 1, MPI_INT, displs, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    MPI_Scatterv(array, sendcounts, displs, MPI_INT, rec_buf, dim, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    if (rank==0) {
    free(sendcounts);
    free(displs);
    }

    int local_max = getMax(rec_buf,dim);
    int global_max;
    MPI_Allreduce(&local_max,&global_max, 1, MPI_INT, MPI_MAX, MPI_COMM_WORLD);



    for (int digit = 1; global_max / digit > 0; digit *= 10) {
        countingSort(array, rec_buf, n, digit, num_process, rank, dim);
    }
    free(rec_buf);
}
```

Also I noticed that using the same kind of approach of calculating the vector of counts locally, but using OpenMP, the speed up reaches maximum value equal to 4.5. Could this result be due to the different architecture used in the two cases? (shared memory for OpenMP and distributed memory for MPI).

For completeness I also report the solution with **OpenMP**:

```
/**
 * @brief This function allows to find the maximum in an array.
 * @param n        array size.
 * @param arr[n]   array.
 */
unsigned getMax(int n, unsigned arr[n]) {
    unsigned mx = arr[0];
    #pragma omp parallel for reduction(max:mx)
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
        if (arr[i] > mx)
            mx = arr[i];
    return mx;
}



/* Source: https://gist.github.com/wanghc78/2c2b403299cab172e74c62f4397a6997 
   Copyright (c) 2014, Haichuan Wang All rights reserved. */
/**
 * @brief The main function that sorts arr[] of size n using Radix Sort
 * @param n        array size.
 * @param arr[n]   array.
 * @param threads  number of threads.
 */
unsigned * radixsort(int n, unsigned arr[n], int threads) {
    if (threads == 0)
    threads+=1;
    
    unsigned m = getMax(n, arr);
    unsigned exp;
    unsigned *output = malloc(n*sizeof(unsigned)); 
    for (exp = 1; m / exp > 0; exp *= 10) {
        int count[10] = {0}, local_count[10] = { 0 };
        
        #pragma omp parallel firstprivate(local_count) num_threads(threads)
        {
        #pragma omp for schedule(static) nowait
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
            local_count[(arr[i] / exp) % 10]++; 
    
        #pragma omp critical 
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
            count[i] += local_count[i]; 

        #pragma omp barrier

        #pragma omp single
        for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
            count[i] += count[i - 1];

        int tid = omp_get_thread_num();
        for(int cur_t = threads - 1; cur_t >= 0; cur_t--) {
            if(cur_t == tid) {
                for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                    count[i] -= local_count[i];
                    local_count[i] = count[i];
                }
            }
            else {
                #pragma omp barrier
            } 
        } 

    #pragma omp for schedule(static)
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)  
            output[local_count[(arr[i] / exp) % 10]++] = arr[i];
            
        }
        unsigned* tmp = arr;
        arr = output;
        output = tmp;
    }
    free(output);
    return arr;
}

/**
 * @brief This function initializes all the data structures needed in the program.
 * @param N        array size.
 * @param threads  number of threads.
 */
unsigned* init_structure(int N, int threads) {
    unsigned * data_vector = malloc(N*sizeof(unsigned));
    #pragma omp parallel for shared(data_vector) num_threads(threads)
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++)
        data_vector[i]=N-i;
    
    return data_vector;
}
```

Thanks everyone for the answers.

Comment: 1. How big is your problem? As a random guess I would say that you need at least a few hundred elements per process to get a good speedup. 2. by turning sorting into a two-step process you're altering the algorithm. Make sure you compare the parallel version to the sequential execution of that same partitioned algorithm, not to a one-level radix or merge sort. 3. Your code is not fully parallel: you have work on the root that gives a sequential bottleneck. 4. Your reduce call with `0` as receive buffer should be `MPI_IN_PLACE`. What you have may work, but I wouldn't guarantee it.

Comment: 1)I made the test sorting an array of 10000000 integers. 2) what did you mean with two-step process? What version i have to use to do the right comparison? 3) I think that for this kind of implementation i need to do the sorting on the root maybe. 4) probably it's the same, i will try with MPI_IN_PLACE. Thanks for your answer.